# Saved data lost when I restart the application(android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm saving some records through my application in `SQLite` database and later retrieving those records for future use.

It's working fine until I close my application.

When I close my application all the previously saved record becomes zero.

Here is the code:--

```
 public long insertAlbum(long Outlet_id,long user_id,String Remarks,String PhotoName,String ReportId,String Date,String Status,String LocalRepId)
 {
     long rowId=0;

     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
     initialValues.put("web_AlbumId", 0);
     initialValues.put("OutletId", Outlet_id);
     initialValues.put("Remarks", Remarks);
     initialValues.put("UserId", user_id);
     initialValues.put("Usr_Entdt", Date);
     initialValues.put("PhotoName", PhotoName);
     initialValues.put("ApprovedYN", "Pending");
     initialValues.put("Status", Status);
     initialValues.put("ReportId", ReportId);
     initialValues.put("LocalReportId", LocalRepId);
     try
     {
         myDataBase.beginTransaction();
      rowId=  myDataBase.insertOrThrow("Album", null, initialValues);
      myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();

     }
     catch(SQLException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally
     {
         myDataBase.endTransaction();
     }
     return rowId;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't happen.
Sounds to me like you're recreating the database when you're opening the database.
Check your code to make sure it's correct

Comment: The code you posted doesn't help. Please post all code related to the DB, especially the one that happens when you create the db and open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say what's going on.  However, my suspicion is that your code is ALWYAYS creating the database.   Are you extending the SQLiteOpenHelper class to create your database?   Check there or post the code for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to to folder where your Sqlite Db file created and check in that file whether the data you saved is present or not . If the data is present in the DB then you need to Retrieve the data from DB

Comment: you can not see or access the database file of your application what you see in your folder that the db which is created before deployment and the database which are being updated is not in your folder its's in mobile app which you can not access

Comment: there are plenty of ways to see your apps sqlite db, you can use adb to shell in and query the db directoy, or copy the db file out onto a workstation with a sqlite editor app.